# Switch with SINGLE case or if else

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I am working on a enormous project and WebStorm inspections always offer me to transform switch constructions with single case or case + default, like this

```html
switch (fieldInfo.Type()) {
        case this.TYPE_NESTED:
            changedFieldInfo.addFieldFromPrototype(proto)
            break;

        default:
            changedFieldInfo._fieldInfo[this.FI_FIELDS] = [];
            break;
    }
```

to if else construction like this

```html
if (fieldInfo.Type() === this.TYPE_NESTED) {
        changedFieldInfo.addFieldFromPrototype(proto);
    } else {
        changedFieldInfo._fieldInfo[this.FI_FIELDS] = [];
    }
```

My colleagues say that switch is more readable even if it has only one case clause, especially when checking for enumerations like TYPE in snippets above.

**What does js community think about that?**
Also assume that we are not going to add second case clause and to go back to a single clause very often, so maintenance issues are minor.

*And one more question*, is it possible to transform switch with break inside the case clause to if without using extra code, eg

```html
    switch (fieldInfo.Type()) {
            case this.TYPE_NESTED:
                if(smthIsTrue)
                    break;
                changedFieldInfo.addFieldFromPrototype(proto)
                break;

            default:
                changedFieldInfo._fieldInfo[this.FI_FIELDS] = [];
                break;
        }
```

Comment: *My colleagues say that switch is more readable even if it has only one case clause* - they are wrong (you may invite them to this discussion). `switch` starts become beneficial on multiple "cases"

Comment: Yes, Switch is the best even it is faster than if-else

Comment: @SalilSharma not in this situation. When we have one case in switch it doesn't matter what we use in terms of performance. Moreover i am asking about code styling and clean code and don't care about losing nanoseconds.

Comment: @Danissimo even for the cleaner code SWITCH only

Comment: @SalilSharma could you explain why? From my point of view if is more readable

Comment: @Danissimo [link](http://example.com)